# how put item from another form ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 form, I want to create in my one form check_box_tag and if I checked same item, this item put in another form in hiden field tag, and when I save my another form value this item save in my database.

**in my view**

```
<% for item in @items %>
  <%= check_box_tag "items[#{item.id}]", item.id, :name => "items[]" %>    
<% end %>

<% form_for(@feedback ) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :item_value %> #this is field in which I want put from one form

<%= f.label :name, "Name" %></td>
<%= f.text_field :name, :style => "width:100%" %>

<%= f.label :phone, "Phone" %>
<%= f.text_field :phone, :style => "width:100%" %>

<%= f.label :email, "Email" %>
<%= f.text_field :email, :style => "width:100%" %>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

**in my controller**

```
...
@item = Item.find(:all)
@feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])

email = ApplicationMailer.create_feedback_rez(@feedback)
email.set_content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8")
ApplicationMailer.deliver(email)

@feedback.save
...
```

How can I do it?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: use JavaScript for that

Comment: can you give me some links on examples? thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as though you would benefit more from setting up a database relationship.  What about creating a relation where feedback has_many items?  Then you can keep your forms separate the way they are, have your checkbox form save a database record in the items table, and link that to the feedback table by its ID?  Depending on why you wanted to use the hidden tag to begin with, you may not even need to if you do it this way.  If this isn't what you're looking for, how bout a little more detail- what are you trying to accomplish?  What does your code do?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called **nested forms**  Here is a good link on working with them http://createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/

Comment: it's not for me, I use rails 2.3